# How to specify the class and the method to make a MS tweak on it?

Tags: objective-c, cydia, theos, cydia-substrate

How to specify the class and the method to make a MS tweak on it ?
There is a lot of classes and methods in every single app or in springboard :( 
Any way to make it easy to find the one I'm gonna work on ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to seek for the stuff you'll use within the dumped headers you have for the app. The names of the classes are usually (at least, in SpringBoard) explicit enough to let you guess their purpose.
Finding the right class/method to hook can be long, but you can use `Flex` (available on the Cydia Store) to browse headers and methods more easily